# Make Ajax call to Express server to retrieve dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express, dictionary

I have a dictionary on my server that is set up by Express. I pushed the dictionary, `chunks`, to the server using the `app.get()` function and set the `url` to `/search`.

Here is that code:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
  var queryString = req.query.query
  console.log(queryString)

  var results = Object.keys(index).reduce(function(a, b) {
    if (b.toLowerCase() === queryString.toLowerCase()) {
      return a.concat(index[b]);
    } else {
      console.log("error")
    }
    return a;
  }, []);

******
  var num_chunks = Math.round(results.length/12)
  var chunks = []

  for (var i=0; i<num_chunks; i++) {
    var j = 12*i
    var sliced = results.slice(j, j+12)

    chunks.push({
      key: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000000000000000) + 1),
      value: sliced
    })
  }
******

  res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
  res.json(results);
});
```

Now on the client side of my website, I want to retrieve chunks and interact with the contents of it. Could anyone tell me how I would implement an Ajax/jQuery call to get the dictionary and then reference it in my client side code?

Here is what my ajax function looks like right now, but it is missing the key elements:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/search',
  data: _needs to be filled in_,
  success: _needs to be filled in_,
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Cheers, Theo

Comment: What is `index`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts its basically a dictionary that i pull data from to create results. not too pertinent to this question though

Comment: Just so you know, if you use `Math.round()` and `results.length % 12` is between 1 and 5, your `chunks` will skip the last 1-5 results.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for the heads up but thats rly not what i was asking this question for. if you know the answer, id rly love the help

Comment: That's why it was a comment and not an answer...